# flutter: firebase works sometimes and other times doesn't

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, ios-simulator, android-studio-3.0

For the past 3 days now I've not been able to update my project due to the fluctuation of the (I don't know if it's the Android studio, IOS simulator, or Firebase console). One moment it works well, the other moment it gives me errors.

With the Android emulator, almost all of them are not connecting to the authentication function. Only one works. Even with this, it doesn't work all the time. (I made sure I signed in to the Play Store before using the emulator) I tried to reinstall the Android Studio, but the situation did not improve.

With the IOS simulator and the physical device, sometimes, after the authentication, it refuses to get data from Firebase. Other times it works.

Sometimes when things seem to work on one emulator, it doesn't on the other. Sometimes when I try to store data on the Firebase Console, My emulator retrieves the stored data, but I don't see the stored data on the Firebase console.

I tried to use VPN but the problem persists. I've been working on this project for the past 1 month and everything was ok until recently.  This is fraustarting.

Any solution?